# Show Battery percentage on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, battery, menu-bar

After I upgraded my mac to big sur the battery on the menu bar only show bar/not percentage like before. How to show percentage again?

I go to battery preference but no that option.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The software changed what shows in the menu bar. Open the dock and menu preferences and enable percentage.

[image: Big Sur Dock and Menu preferences for battery display]

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-dock-menu-bar-preferences-mchlp1119/mac